# Eliminate render-blocking resources font on amp pages

Tags: html, css, fonts, amp-html, lighthouse

Google Lighthouse raising issues of AMP Pages
[image]

I tried multiple solutions but not working

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,600,700,900&display=swap" as="font" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo:300,400,600,700&subset=arabic,latin-ext&display=swap" as="font" crossorigin>
```

Comment: also use: `<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />`

Comment: Not working @JayGray

Comment: we have a similar config but don't see this specific issue (fonts). what happens if you temporarily remove font-awesome? are google fonts still flagged by lighthouse?

Comment: No but we need them

Comment: Understood. We don't use font-awesome (because of size) and don't have the issue you are having. That's why i suggested removing FA temporarily to see if the problem resolved. You might try self-hosting. Here's another idea. Try *adding* this: `@font-face {font-family:system; font-style:normal; font-weight:400; src:local("Roboto-Light");}` That might help render Roboto before the google library is loaded.

Comment: Instead of font-awesome use SVG image icons, also check the AMP page on https://amp.dev/page-experience/ and implement the suggestions

Comment: For other devs: Put the google fonts onto your own web server if you can :)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me (put in HTML index):

```
<style>
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
 family=Open+Sans:wght@500;600;700;800&display=swap');
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a onload listener to change the `rel` attribute from `preload` to `stylesheet`

this will look something like:

```html
<link
  rel="preload"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,600,700,900&display=swap"
  onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'"
  as="style"
>
```

You can read more about this topic at [web.dev](https://web.dev/defer-non-critical-css/#optimize)

Comment: What happens to critical css and font display  before load?

Answer (score -1):

[web.dev](https://web.dev/defer-non-critical-css/) says that you should preload in this way:

```
<link rel="preload" 
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,600,700,900&display=swap"
      as="style"
      onload="this.onload=null; this.rel='stylesheet'; document.body.classList.add('fonts-loaded')">
```

But use another font till fonts are loaded:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body.fonts-loaded {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```